# Auth::user() returns null with the user logged in but works in blade template

Tags: authentication, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6 and in the controller store method, `Auth::user()` returns `null` even when the user is logged in but works in blade template. I have gone through similar questions but nothing is working.

I am posting to an API route and I am not sure whether this is the reason. Kindly assist.

Comment: "*I am posting to an API route and I am not sure whether this is the reason.*" - It likely is. `API` routes and the Controllers associated with them are not configured to use the `Auth()` logic (via `Middleware`). APIs are meant to be stateless.

Comment: they can use the authentication system just fine, they just use a different guard that doesn't use sessions

Answer (score 0):

If you have not adjusted the `api` web group or the `RouteServiceProvider` that comes with the default application you will not have any session support in your API routes (`routes/api.php`). The APIs are usually stateless so no session support. If you want to deal with authentication using the built in authentication system you would want to deal with a token based system. The default `api` guard that is setup for you will use the `TokenGuard` which will look in the request for a token being passed to authenticate the user against. You would need to assign the middleware `auth` with the parameter `api`, to specify the `api` guard, `auth:api`.

If you send a request correctly to one of these end points now, including the token, you will have a user returned from `Auth::user()` or `$request->user()` etc.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - API Authentication - Passing Tokens in Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - API Authentication - Protected Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication#protecting-routes) `auth:api`

Pleease read the whole section for a better understanding of using this type of Guard with the built in Authentication system:

[Laravel 6.x Docs - API Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)

If you don't want to deal with a "stateless" API, and you would rather use sessions you can just move your API routes to the `web.php` file and prefix them with `api`.